# 行く when comparing age

Tags: meaning, verbs

I can't understand the use of "行っていた" in following line from the book "死者の学園祭" by 赤川次郎:

> 手塚校長は父の旧友という事だったが、年齢は父より大分**行っていた**。

I assume it means the principal is older, but I can't tell from the context what the relation is between their ages, and no dictionary entry for 行く or 行う seems to be relevant. Does the bolded text mean the same as if he had said 年上だった?

Comment: [goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/225173/m0u/) meaning #11に「 年をとる。成長する。」とありますが、参考になりますか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **行{い}く**.

Set phrases like 年{とし}が行{い}く means "grow old". And it's not three-year-old "old" but really advanced in years. There's a similar expression 年{とし}を取{と}る, whereas 年が行く suggests more like the speaker is talking from younger eyes, in my personal sense.